# How to get annotation property value in the aspect?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-aop

Annotation definition:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class RequireEnabledFeature(val featureName:String) {
}
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
class RequireEnabledFeatureAspect {
    @Around(
        value = "execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(RequireEnabledFeature)"
    )
    fun requireEnabledFeature(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any? {
        return joinPoint.proceed()
    }
}
```

Using the annotation:

```
@RequireEnabledFeature("something")
fun someFction()
```

Now the question is how can I get the feature name value in Kotlin? Injecting annotation object in the point cut was also not working. Any idea? It seems like using joinPoint I can get `joinPoint.target.javaClass.methods[1].annotations[0]` which is the Proxy for `AnnotationInvocationHandler` but I am not unable to get the propert value from there.

Comment: u mean ur Advice is not executing ? and also can u confirm is that your actual code, I am not aware of Kotlin ?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try in your @Around function:

```
val theMethod = (joinPoint.signature as MethodSignature).method
val myAnnotation = theMethod.getAnnotation(RequireEnabledFeature::class.java)
println(myAnnotation.featureName) // here you get the annotation's properties
```

Comment: Reflection is unnecessary for this kind of use case.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the annotation to an advice method parameter like this (I do not speak Kotlin, so I am writing this without having compiled it):

```kotlin
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(feature)")
fun requireEnabledFeature(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint, RequireEnabledFeature feature): Any? {
  println(feature.featureName)
  return joinPoint.proceed()
}
```